# How can you conditionally run an MSBuild task only when your project outputs have been built?

Tags: msbuild

I want to run an MSBuild Task (which signs an executable/dll) but only when the output exe/dll has changed. If none of the source files have changed causing a recompile of the exe/dll then I don't want the task to run.

Despite spending several hours trying different things out I cannot work out how to get my target task to only run if the project has been compiled where the output files have changed (in other words the CoreCompile target was not skipped I think).

Answer (score 5):

You can just do this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>DoStuffWithNewlyCompiledAssembly</TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works because someone smart at Microsoft added the following line at the end of the `CoreCompile` target in `Microsoft.[CSharp|VisualBasic][.Core].targets` (the file name depends on the language and MSBuild/Visual Studio version).

```
<CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''"/>
```

So if you specify a target name in the `TargetsTriggeredByCompilation` property, your target will run if `CoreCompile` runs-- and your target will not run if `CoreCompile` is skipped (e.g. because the output assembly is already up-to-date with respect to the code).

Answer (score 2):

Should be the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961973/msbuild-conditional-exec/4030065#4030065), using the [TargetOutputs parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx)::

```
<MSBuild Projects="File.sln" >
   <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects" />
</MSBuild>
<Message Text="Assemblies built: @(AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects)" /> <!-- just for debug -->
<CallTarget Targets="SignExe" Condition="'@(AssembliesBuiltByChildProjects)'!=''" />
```

Comment: I think this is a different approach - I'm trying to understand how to do this in the context of a project file .csproj for a regular project - not creating an MSBuild project file that targets solutions